# Why does params behave differently for an array of strings and an array of integers?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parameters, nunit

When writing my unit tests, I stumbled upon a problem: NUnit's `[TestCaseAttribute]`, with the following constructor overloads:

```
public TestCaseAttribute(params object arg)
public TestCaseAttribute(params object args[])
```

would accept an array of integers, and a list of arguments including an array of strings, but would not accept an array of strings itself:

```
[TestCaseAttribute(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })] //works
[TestCaseAttribute("Other string", new[] { "1", "2", "3" })] //works
[TestCaseAttribute(new[] { "1", "2", "3" })] //compilation error?
```

This surprised me, so I verified the behavior:

```
private static void PrintTypes(params object[] objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array type is " + objects.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("Object count is " + objects.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Object type is " + objects[0].GetType());
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array of ints: ");
    PrintTypes(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Array of strings: ");
    PrintTypes(new[] { "1", "2", "3" });
}
```

The output is somewhat baffling to me - it seems like the integer array is treated as a single object, but a string array is unrolled:

```
Array of ints:
Array type is System.Object[]
Object count is 1
Object type is System.Int32[]

Array of strings:
Array type is System.String[]
Object count is 3
Object type is System.String
```

And if we add the following method:

```
private static void PrintTypes(object obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In object method");
    Console.WriteLine("Object type is " + obj.GetType());
}
```

the compiler seems to prefer it for an array of ints, but not for an array of strings:

```
Array of ints: 
In object method
Object type is System.Int32[]

Array of strings: 
In array method
Array type is System.String[]
Object count is 3
Object type is System.String
```

Why is that the case? I'm assuming it has something to do with the integers not being reference types, but I'd like more of an explanation as to what exactly dictates that the compiler prefers different overloads for different arrays, and why one is allowable for the attribute constructor, but not the other.

Comment: Can you please check the signature of the TestCaseAttribute constructors. I don't think that the argument is `params object[]` as you claim. It seems to me that there are a several contructors, among them `params int[]` and `string, params string[]` variants or similar. With regard to your PrintTypes method, see my answer below.

Comment: I checked the constructor overloads for TestCaseAttribute. I'll update my answer shortly...

Comment: I have expanded my answer below. TL;DR: The `string[]` argument would require an implicit reference conversion, which is not permitted for attribute arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with `int` not being a reference type being the reason for the observed behavior with your *PrintTypes* test method.

According to the C# specification ([link](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)), chapter 15.6.2.5
Parameter arrays:

> A parameter array permits arguments to be specified in one of two ways
>   in a method invocation:
>
> • The argument given for a parameter array can be a single expression that is implicitly convertible (§11.2) to the parameter array type. In this case, the parameter array acts precisely like a value  parameter.

Chapter 11.2 (Implicit reference conversions) explains what "implicitly convertible" means with respect to arrays:

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> [...]
>
> • From an array-type S with an element type SE to an array-type T with an element type TE, provided all of the following are true:
>
> - S and  T differ only in element type. In other words, S and 
>   T have the same number of dimensions.
>
> - An implicit reference conversion exists from SE to TE

Note that the existence of an implicit reference conversion is a requirement here. A conversion from a value type to a reference type is not an (implicit) reference conversion  (see chapter 11.2 again). This is the reason why the the int[] array is just being treated as a single object argument, which leads to *PrintTypes* being called in expanded form.

Now, why then is

```
[TestCaseAttribute(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })] //works
```

compiling, while

```
[TestCaseAttribute(new[] { "1", "2", "3" })] //compilation error?
```

is not? Does it not contradict what i just said?

Lets take a look at the constructors of `TestCaseAttribute`:

```
public TestCaseAttribute(params object[] arguments);
public TestCaseAttribute(object arg);
public TestCaseAttribute(object arg1, object arg2);
public TestCaseAttribute(object arg1, object arg2, object arg3);
```

From the explanation given above, it should be clear that `[TestCaseAttribute(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })]` is compiling, because it uses the `TestCaseAttribute(object arg)` constructor overload.

`new[] { "1", "2", "3" }` is a string array, and the compiler choses as best matching overload for this argument `TestCaseAttribute(params object args[])` (according to the rules explained in chapter 12.6.4 Overload resolution). Unfortunately, the overload resolution does not take the special requirement for attributes into account that attribute arguments have to be constant expressions. The rules for constant expressions (chapter 12.20 Constant expressions) state:

> Note: Other conversions including boxing, unboxing, and **implicit
>   reference conversions of non-null values are not permitted in constant
>   expressions**.

(emphasis mine)

And this is what leads to the compiler error with regard to the attribute. The compiler chooses a constructor overload it thinks best fits the `string[]` argument. Then, at a later stage of the compilation process the compiler is trying to apply the attribute. It notices that a required implicit reference conversion is not permitted for attribute arguments, which results in the observed compile error.

Comment: Thanks, that would be it! What's still interesting to me though is why this conversion causes the C# compiler to no longer recognize the string array as a valid attribute constructor argument - I can pass my array of string to a constructor accepting either `string[]` or `object`, but not `object[]`.